# How to count every row base on array postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have table follow that contain user_id and follower_ids in int array:

```
id | user_id | follower_ids
---|---------|-------------
1  | 1       | {2,3,4}
2  | 2       | {1}
3  | 3       | {1,2}
4  | 4       | {1}
```

I want to get result like this

```
user_id | count
--------| -----
1       | 3
2       | 2
3       | 1
4       | 1
```

how do i run a query?

Thank you.

Comment: do you need to calculate the number of followers for each user?

Comment: yes i need to count number of followers for each user.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_length()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) function

```
select user_id
      ,array_length(follower_ids,1) count
from bar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t(id,user_id,follower_ids) AS ( VALUES
  (1,1,ARRAY[2,3,4]),
  (2,2,ARRAY[1]),
  (3,3,ARRAY[1,2]),
  (3,4,ARRAY[1])
)
SELECT
  follower AS user_id,
  count(follower) AS follower_count
FROM t,unnest(t.follower_ids) AS follower
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Output:

```
 user_id | follower_count 
---------+----------------
       1 |              3
       2 |              2
       3 |              1
       4 |              1
(4 rows)
```